# Limit the list of objects sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am new to SQL (using SQLiteStudio) and I wrote such a query to calculate. List of municipalities where the number of sales increased by at least 20% between the first and second quarters of 2020. I'm trying to set a limit using HAVING but it doesn't work. Any help would really help. Thanks!

```
    SELECT commune, p.date_1,d.date_2,
    (((d.date_2)*100/(p.date_1)-100)) as "Sales"
    FROM pr_semestr p, dx_semestre d
    WHERE p.commune=d.commune
    HAVING ( (d.date_2)*100/(p.date_1)-100) > '20'
```

Data Sample:

| commune | date_1 | date_2 | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABBEVILLE | 2 | 9 | 350 |
| ACHERES | 5 | 13 | 160 |
| ACIGNE | 11 | 8 | -28 |
| AGEN | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| AIGUES-VIVES | 15 | 17 | 13 |

Comment: Fyi Sqlite supports [modern join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAVING clause is used to filter GROUPed data. Use a WHERE clause to filter selected row data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I changed using a WHERE clause, also added one parenthesis and deleted quotes. And also changed on JOIN ON. It worked!

```
    FROM pr_semestr p JOIN dx_semestre d ON p.commune=d.commune
    WHERE (((d.date_2)*100/(p.date_1)-100)) > 20
```